# How to set Minimum and Maximum Values of x and y axis in Flutter Charts?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, flutter-charts

Right now I am passing the list of two data's Timer1 and FP7 and the wave is also coming. But now I want to set this in Intervals of 10 seconds. I am using syncfusion Library and reffering this [This Link](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/how-to-create-a-real-time-flutter-chart-in-10-minutes/blob/main/lib/main.dart). But I am not able to set Intervals. Can anyone please help me with this or Direct me to any reference where this is done.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1: How to set Minimum and Maximum Values of x and y axis in Flutter Charts.**

You can set the [minimum](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/minimum.html) and [maximum](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/maximum.html) of the x and y axis with the help of minimum and maximum properties in the axis. You can use the [visibleMinimum](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/visibleMinimum.html) and [visibleMaximum](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/visibleMaximum.html) properties of the chart axis too and these properties are used to set the minimum and maximum visible range of an axis.

**Query 2: I am passing the list of two data's Timer1 and FP7 and the wave is also coming. But now I want to set this in Intervals of 10 seconds.**

Add a data point at every 10 seconds interval, you can simply set the duration value to 10, as shown in the code snippet below.